# Subgroup generated by $\langle a,b \rangle$ where $ab=ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a,b$ be elements of a group G such that $ab = ba.$  Prove that $\langle a,b \rangle = \{ a^nb^m : n,m \in \mathbf{Z} \}.$

I am having a difficult time starting this proof.

I know that $\langle a \rangle = \{ e, a^1, a^2, \cdots , a^{n-1} \}$ and similarly $\langle b \rangle = \{ e, b^1, b^2, \cdots , b^{n-1} \}$.

Then $\langle a,b \rangle =$ all possible "words" of the form $a^nb^m : n,m \in \mathbf{Z}$.

Am I on the correct track?  Any hints would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You say that you "know that $\langle a\rangle=\{e,a^1,a^2,\dots,a^{n-1}\}$", but that is not correct.

Comment: Should I have said $\langle a \rangle = \{ a^n = e : n \in \mathbf{Z} \}$ ? @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: No, that is slightly worse, as it does not even make sense :-) You should have writtten something like «$\langle a\rangle=\{a^n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$».

Comment: I should have studied theology, where rigor is of unimportance!

Comment: This does not have anything to do with rigor, really. What you wrote originally was wrong, not unrigorous, and what you wrote in the comment was meaningless (the "$a^n=e$" on the left of the colon in the set cannot be there), not unrigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $S:=\{ a^nb^m : n,m \in \mathbf{Z} \}$ is certainly contained in $\langle a,b\rangle$. To show that $\langle a,b\rangle$ is not larger than that it suffices to shows that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$. To do so one shows   that $S$ is not empty, is closed under multiplication, and closed under taking inverses. Indeed, $a^0b^0\in S$, $a^nb^m\cdot a^{r}b^s\stackrel !=a^{n+r}b^{m+s}\in S$, and $(a^nb^m)^{-1}\stackrel!=a^{-n}b^{-m}\in S$. You are probably expected the correctness of the  equalities marked with "!" by induction.

Comment: Thank you very much.  In this idea, are you ever using the fact that $a$ and $b$ commute?

Comment: «it suffices to shows that S is a subgroup of G» **and** that it contains both $a$ and $b$, actually.